# How to Connect MySql Database on REST service start-up?

Tags: java, rest

**Using REST service with Apache Tomcat 7 and Jersey Jars.**

I am developing a android application which gets and post some data on server through REST service in java.For each request from android client the REST server Opens database connection, executes query, returns the result and closes database connection..

```
public String postPerson(
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> personParams
            ) {

                 EmployeeData empD=new EmployeeData();
                 //Connecting with database on empty constructor

                 int id = personParams.getFirst(EMPLOYEE_ID);


                String employeeDepartment=empD.getDepartment(id);
                //Getting department name 

                empD.disconnectDb();

                return(empD);                                     
    }
```

The above scenario is working fine but not efficient response time.
Now i want to create database connection on REST Service start-up to decrease the response time to android client.. How can i achieve this ????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the following links. I hope that those links will solve your problem but remember that never perform the concurrent transaction over the same database connection. By following the procedure you will be also able to establish connection to asterisk management interface at service start up.

http://www.programcreek.com/2009/07/put-database-connection-to-servletcontextlistener/

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B15904_01/web.1012/b14017/filters.htm#i1000654

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of Connection Pooling to increase response time as creation of connections on the fly is expensive.

[Apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) is a good Connection Pooling library.

This is an [example](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/dbcp/trunk/doc/PoolingDataSourceExample.java?view=markup) on how to make use of Connection Pooling using Apache DBCP